# Adjecive that means overgrown by alien life

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a word to describe terrain which is occupied by native alien life.

On Earth, I might talk about a *lush* valley in need of environmental protection or *verdant* hills that would be perfect for vineyards. These adjectives have positive connotations of beauty and suitability for human habitation. What adjective would space colonists use to describe exo-planet terrain populated by alien life, especially plant-like life they consider repulsive or hazardous?

*Infested* and *blighted* convey disgust and danger, and would be good descriptions if alien life was invading Earth. In this case, the alien life is in its own native environment.

*Teeming* and *crawling* could describe animal-like aliens, but don't work for plant-like ones. They also share a problem with *overgrown*: they don't make a distinction about the life being unnatural from a human perspective.

Is there a single word that will convey this fairly complex idea? I'm fine with an obscure word used by Lovecraft or 1950's science fiction if I can avoid a multi-word phrase or neologism.

> The planetary survey described barren mountains, _______ lowlands, and warm oceans teeming with alien life.

An obscure word I'm considering is *xenic*. I thought it was a neologism, but I discovered it can refer to a microbial culture containing unknown organisms. This is close to what I'm looking for, but not perfect. Is there a similar scientific adjective that better fits my criteria?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think *infested* would be OK if the alien life is viewed negatively. And what's wrong with *overgrown*? Other options are *overrun, rank, rife*. By the way, it is formally required that you provide an example sentence with a single-word request on this site (hover over the tag to learn more).

Comment: Uh, if this "life" is native to the planet then it's not "alien".

Comment: @HotLicks From a human perspective, any life that didn't originate on Earth is alien.

Comment: [Rife](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rife) would seem to be useful here. It is commonly used with respect to an abundance of unwantedness.

Comment: @Ben - Alas, that is apt to be the attitude of many humans.

Comment: *Overgrown* would seem to fit the sentence. As to *xenic*, I have no objections to it either, but its meaning would not fit the question's conditions. It is synonymous with *alien*, so you could then use that word as well.

Comment: @Cerberus *Lush, verdant, overgrown, and infested* all fit the sentence grammatically but don't match the connotations I'm after. I consider *overgrown* and *infested* closest among common words. The distinction I'd draw between *alien* and *xenic* is that *alien* could refer to technology or a planet (in addition to life), while *xenic* is more focused on exotic life.

Comment: @KannE Humans travel to a distant star, with the intention of colonizing one of its planets. They discover that their new home is covered with a thick blanket of waxy black alien fungus, sulfurous yellow fern-like plants, fleshy blobs that stink because their version of photosynthesis involves ammonia, or whatever. Gross!

Answer (score 1):

**Native flora**

> flora - The plants of a particular region, habitat, or geological
>   period.
>
> 'Britain's native flora'  [ODD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flora)

Substitute your planet's name for 'Britain'.

BTW, welcome to English Language & Usage.

**EDIT**

If you want to include animals then

> Native flora and
>   [fauna](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fauna)

Comment: "lush native flora and fauna" or even "alien flora and fauna" would work in your sentence.

Comment: This is not an adjective that could be used to describe terrain.

Comment: "...lush your-plant-name flora and fauna covered lowlands...".  Substituting earth yields, "...lush earth flora and fauna covered lowlands...".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [***fecund***](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/us/amp/english/fecund) would work for you. Its literal meaning is just *fruitful* or *fertile* (Collins Dictionary) but, perhaps due to its relative rarity and similarity to words like *fungus* and *fecal*, it has less purely-positive connotations than its synonyms. As one online article puts it

> **Definition**: Fruitful in offspring or vegetation.
>
> You would never guess from the sound of it that this word actually refers to something positive. There is just something about it that feels a bit off, and, in fact, the term is a regular on many lists of [most hated words](http://blog.dictionary.com/gross-sounding/). Sorry, fecund (*shudders*).

—[Lily Feinn, "11 Words That Sound Dirty, But Actually Aren't, According To Reddit", *Bustle*, Dec 23 2016](https://www.bustle.com/p/11-words-that-sound-dirty-but-actually-arent-according-to-reddit-26010)

For an even more obscure variant, the Oxford English Dictionary includes an entry for the now-obsolete synonym *fecundous*, which to my ear sounds even less salubrious.

So your sentence could read

> The planetary survey described barren mountains, **fecund(ous)** lowlands, and warm oceans teeming with alien life.

---

<sub>It doesn't fit neatly into your existing sentence, but you could also potentially take advantage of the varying usages of [*endemic*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/endemic) to good effect. This word originally just meant *native* to a place, but has gained the meaning *common* in a place, and has come to be associated especially with disease. So calling the planet's lifeforms *endemic* sounds more ominous and invasive than just saying that they're native.</sub>

Comment: Endemic does derive from the Greek root *demos* (people), so I could mash it together with a Greek prefix like *xeno-* to produce *xenodemic* (with a broad interpretation of "people"). It's a shame *xenobiotic* already has a somewhat unrelated definition.